# Cannot connect to Microsoft SQL Server using Knex.js

Tags: sql-server, node.js, knex.js

I am trying to connect to Microsoft SQL server using Knex.js . Below is the config option for connection I am providing :-

```
development: {
        client: 'mssql',
        connection: {
            host:process.env.APP_DB_HOST,
            database:process.env.APP_DB_NAME,
            user: process.env.LOCAL_POSTGRES_USER,
            password: process.env.LOCAL_POSTGRES_PASS
        }
```

The connection is not occurring and even I am not getting any error also.

Comment: You said you're not getting any errors, so it may be helpful to update your question to show how you are testing your connection and why you believe you're not connecting to the db. Couple of potential causes: Are your environment variables correct? Are you using the right ones... `LOCAL_POSTGRES_USER`? It looks like you've set up your knexfile to be environment specific, so is your `NODE_ENV` set to `production`? Are you fetching the configuration file correctly, i.e. something like `require('./knexfile')[process.env.NODE_ENV]`?

Comment: Currently I am able to connect to postegre sql. And I am planning to migrate to SQL Server. So I changes the Knexfile.js  development: {
    client: 'mssql',
    connection: {
      host:process.env.APP_DB_HOST,
      database:process.env.APP_DB_NAME,
      user: process.env.LOCAL_POSTGRES_USER,
      password: process.env.LOCAL_POSTGRES_PASS
    }
  }. And Why I said it was not working that I am not getting the result. If I change it to postegre I am getting the result